# Clearing Active Error Events In IBM IMM 2

Tags: monitoring, ibm, imm2

A while ago a server crashed. The issue was fixed, but IMM2 still shows the error under 'Active Events'. This means that system status is constantly 'WARNING' in our monitoring solution. We cleared the event log, but the error event is still shown under 'Active Events', although the event log is now empty. The IMM2 user guide does not mention this, we tried to use the `clearlog` command, but that is just the CLI way to clear the event log, and does not clear 'Active Events'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Restart the IMM2. This does not restart the physical server.

Comment: IMM restart was indeed the solution. Please note however, that you should not ask for clarification in answers.

Comment: Can't believe that's how it's supposed to work.